# Symfony - access object of non related tables

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

How can i access the object of second table when joined (non-related tables)?

I have two table which are not related and I want to get the object of the second class (from below dump output)

[My repository with dump](https://gist.github.com/gghhh456/e640648c77038aa911d7)

For example:

my controller:

```
$ProductSet_Repo = $em->getRepository('MyTestBundle:Product\ProductSet')->FindProductSet($productid);
```

Normally when the tables are related I can simple do

`$productSet =   $ProductSet_Repo->getproductid()->getProduct();` to get the object of `Product class` From `ProductSet Class`.

[See My Dump](https://gist.github.com/gghhh456/e640648c77038aa911d7#file-dump)

However since the tables are not in relationship and when i dump the data i get the objects of two classes is there a way I can access the Object `My\TestBundle:Products\Entity\Product\ProductSet` and `\My\TestBundle\Entity\Product\Product`?

Note: i don't want to do establish relationship between the two tables as I am working on already existing table for which i don't want to make any changes

Also I know I can select the fields which i want to retrieve. (I dont want to do that)

Comment: add all code, that specify your problem to the question. Your question is unclear.

Comment: btw, it would be nice if you provide small example of what you expecting to get.

Comment: Okay I have edited my Question and provided an example

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. You would like to get Product objects from a given ProductSet object ?

What kind of result are you expecting ?

Comment: Yes i would like to get Product objects from a given product set object.. if you look at the dump u see clearly two objects  product set and product. I cannt access product object

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> i don't want to do establish relationship between the two tables as I am working on already existing table for which i don't want to make any changes.

But with doctrine you are very well able to make a association between two entities without changing the tables. As far as I can see from your query you have a `product_id` column in your `product_set` table. That is all you need to make an association between `Product` and `ProductSet`.

In your `ProductSet` class you can do:

```
<?php

namespace My\TestBundle\Entity\Product;

class ProductSet
{
    //... other properties

    /**
     * @var Product
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\TestBundle\Entity\Product\Product")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;

    /**
     * Set the product.
     *
     * @param Product $product
     * @return ProductSet
     */ 
    public function setProduct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the product.
     *
     * @return Product
     */ 
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    //... other setters and getters
}
```

Now you can do:

```
$repository = $em->getRepository('MyTestBundle:Product\ProductSet')
$productSets = $repository->findBy(array('product' => $productid));

foreach($productSets as $productSet){
    $productSet->getProduct()->getId() === $productId; // true
}
```

Comment: But the problem is I got two tables in manytomany relationship with no third table for reference.. it was developed by previous webdeveloper and i dont want to spend more time as i work as free lancer.

Comment: Hence I dont want to make any association between the two table.  I really dont care about the redundant-data  or performance.

Comment: Okay will try without doctrine

Answer (score 0):

You can still join them (despite of strange naming convention you have id of corresponding object in the other entity) using query builder or native sql, but it's a really bad way.

> it was developed by previous webdeveloper and i dont want to spend more time as i work as free lancer

That's not an excuse. You should create a relation and migration for these data. Getting money for a poorly designed and developed app is not cool.

Probably additional work when working with that poor design will take your more time than doing it in a proper way.

Comment: I have already disussed with my client n hopefully next year we gonna work on a new system next year.. Its only a temperory solution untill the new system is ready